# Can't remove table border, trying to find what is causing this

Tags: html, css, html-table, border

The blue field where I've put my price seems to have border on the left and right side so it doesn't fill up the entire table from with 100% width.

```
<td class="price">€ 299,-</td>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XzU58/

How can I fix this, I can't seem to find what I'm exactly doing wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following:

```
.pricetable{
     color: #FFF;
     text-align: center;
     border-collapse: collapse; // Add this to your CSS
   }
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/XzU58/2/)

Answer (score 0):

```
.pricetable, .table-header {
    background: #262932;
    color: #FFF;
    text-align: center;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**[See this demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/XzU58/3/)**

You need to use `border-collapse: collapse;`

```
table.pricetable {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to make any changes to your CSS, you can add a `cellspacing` and a `cellpadding` to a value of `0`. This will also make your table to remove the spacing (i.e the border that you have mentioned) that you  are getting.

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/XzU58/4/)**

**The Code:**

```
<table class="pricetable" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
```